Error when trying to load in curl package in R
When I try to load in the curl package in R I get the following error message:
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-x86_64/Resources/library/curl/libs/curl.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-x86_64/Resources/library/curl/libs/curl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace (_curl_url_strerror)

I've removed the package and installed again as well as downloading the package by source. I've also updated rstudio and r. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I tried install.packages("curl") and library(curl). It works. [R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31 ucrt)]

Yea I tried that and it gives me the same error message I posted above

Reading reddit and github on MacOS you have to install curl before R curl package.  In particular brew install curl pkg-config.

when i run that line it says it is already installed and up to date and gives me a error message when installing the package from source

I was able to solve the error by just updating my mac, thanks for the help in providing that github link where it led me to find the solution
